# ActiveRecord.where ineffective in rake task, works in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake, rake-task

I have this rake task set up to run on a production server through Cloud66 jobs every 3 minutes. It's purpose is to release reservations made for bookings that were abandoned during checkout. The job runs successfully, but is ineffective when run as a rake task.

```rb
namespace :order do
  desc "Unreserves bookings that have had no activity for 5 minutes"
  task release_abandoned_bookings: :environment do
    abandoned_bookings = PhysicalBookingBase.where("reserved = true AND state IN (?) AND updated_at < ?", ['personal_data','awaiting_payment'], 5.minutes.ago)
    abandoned_bookings.update_all(reserved:false)
    puts "Released #{abandoned_bookings.count} abandoned bookings" # = Released 0 abandoned bookings
  end
```

This effect is the same when I ssh into the server and run `bundle exec rake order:release_abandoned_bookings`

However, if I ssh into the server, copy/paste the two essential lines and run them in rails console there they do what they are supposed to:

```sh
pry(main)> abandoned_bookings = PhysicalBookingBase.where("reserved = true AND state IN (?) AND updated_at < ?", ['personal_data','awaiting_payment'], 5.minutes.ago)
  PhysicalBookingBase Load (17.1ms)  SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings" WHERE "bookings"."type" IN ($1, $2, $3) AND (reserved = true AND state IN ('personal_data','awaiting_payment') AND updated_at < '2020-10-30 15:41:45.986908')  [["type", "PhysicalBookingBase"], ["type", "OrganizationBooking"], ["type", "Booking"]]
=> [#<OrganizationBooking id: 39578, reserved: true, state: "personal_data", updated_at: "2020-10-30 15:08:19">]
​
[3] pry(main)> abandoned_bookings.update_all(reserved:false)
  PhysicalBookingBase Update All (18.7ms)  UPDATE "bookings" SET "reserved" = $1 WHERE "bookings"."type" IN ($2, $3, $4) AND (reserved = true AND state IN ('personal_data','awaiting_payment') AND updated_at < '2020-10-30 15:41:45.986908')  [["reserved", false], ["type", "PhysicalBookingBase"], ["type", "OrganizationBooking"], ["type", "Booking"]]
=> 1
​
[4] pry(main)> PhysicalBookingBase.where("reserved = true AND state IN (?) AND updated_at < ?", ['personal_data','awaiting_payment'], 5.minutes.ago)
  PhysicalBookingBase Load (16.3ms)  SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings" WHERE "bookings"."type" IN ($1, $2, $3) AND (reserved = true AND state IN ('personal_data','awaiting_payment') AND updated_at < '2020-10-30 15:41:56.885991')  [["type", "PhysicalBookingBase"], ["type", "OrganizationBooking"], ["type", "Booking"]]
=> []
```

Comment: Is this in production? if so the command would be `bundle exec rake order:release_abandoned_bookings RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: Is the rake task working correctly on local?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Turns out that it's an STI-related problem. Since `PhysicalBookingBase` is an intermediary base class when this runs as a rake task it never finds any records. No records in the DB have "PhysicalBookingBase" in the `type` field.

**TL;DR** The solution was to use `BookingBase` with conditions on the `type` field as the base for the predicate when looking up the bookings.

The STI hierarchy looks like this:

- `PhysicalBookingBase` inherits from `BookingBase`, which has the reference to the table name.
- `Booking` and other variants that have representations in the `type` column in the table inherit from `PhysicalBookingBase`
- In addition we have `DigitalBookingBase` that also inherits from `BookingBase` which follows the same structure

For some reason when running in the Rails app or the Rails Console, using `PhysicalBookingBase` as base for the predicate works just fine, but not when rake runs the same line of code. I even tried adding the [officially suggested STI Preload module](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#single-table-inheritance), but that didn't help either.